# Is there a way to classify two date columns by column name in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

PostgreSQL 8.0.2; table in Redshift

I have a table with two date columns that represent the start and end date of a case. I am trying to get a weekly count of how many cases were started and resolved each week.

**TABLE**

The table contains case IDs, case start date, start week, case resolved date, resolved week:

```
case_id | start_date | start_week | resolved_date | resolved_week
--------+------------+------------+---------------+--------------
101     | 2020-01-01 |     1      | 2020-01-09    |      2
102     | 2020-01-01 |     1      | 2020-01-11    |      2
103     | 2020-01-09 |     2      | 2020-01-11    |      2
104     | 2020-01-10 |     2      | 2020-01-12    |      2
105     | 2020-01-17 |     3      | 2020-01-18    |      3
106     | 2020-01-25 |     4      | 2020-01-25    |      4
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

I need to organize the data by 'week #' and have a count of how many cases were started and resolved, like this:

```
week | date_type | count
-----+-----------+------
  1  |  start    |  2
  2  |  start    |  2
  2  |  resolved |  4
  3  |  start    |  1
  3  |  resolved |  1
  4  |  start    |  1
  4  |  resolved |  1
```

At first, I thought I could use a `CASE` statement to classify the dates into *start* and *resolved* categories, but I think `CASE` can only be used within records, not with columns.

I've tried `COALESCE` in the `SELECT` clause and this does combine all the dates into one column, but I don't know how to separate them out into *start* and *resolved*:

```
SELECT COALESCE(start_date, resolved_date) as "week", COUNT(case_id)
FROM table_1
GROUP BY 1;
```

**CURRENT RESULT**

Produces:

```
week | count
-----+------
  1  |  2
  2  |  6
  3  |  2
  4  |  2
```

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Redshift?  While they have some relation, they are not the same thing.

Comment: `select version();` gives "PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu......Redshift 1.0.24421"

Comment: "CASE can only be used within records, not with columns" - sorry but this is completely backwards.  In a database terminology records are referred to as rows (aka tuples). And rows consistent of columns. Now restricting ourselves to just that domain, CASE can **only** be used with columns not rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Redshift, you would use `union all` to unpivot and then aggregation:

```
select week, what, count(*)
from ((select start_week as week, 'start' as what
       from t
      ) union all
      (select resolved_week as week, 'resolved' as what
       from t
      )
     ) w
group by week, what
order by week;
```